# How to plot this set $M\subset\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: plotting

Is there a way to plot the following set with Mathematica?

$M=\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\:,\:y=\left|x\right|\:,\:0\leq y<z\right\}$

I think it's suppose to look something like this:

[image]

$y=|x|$ is plotted just for reference, and also $(0,0,0)\notin M$ (the origin is not part of the region), but I don't mind if the plot includes this point.

Answer (score 2):

We define `regionplot[]` to take two arguments:  `w` is the region, and `p` is the number of points passed to `PlotPoints`.

```
regionplot[w_, p_] := RegionPlot3D[w, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[LightBlue, Thick], Mesh -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> p, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxRecursion -> 5, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
```

We found that plotting the pair of walls with no thickness, leaves quite a gap between the walls.  Giving the walls a little thickness, and using `p=200` for a nice pinstripe pattern:

```
regionplot[0 < y < z && Abs[x] - .001 < y < Abs[x] + .001, 200]
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to smooth the surface and to get rid of the gap there?

Comment: Yes, I know, it is disappointing!  Using `PlotPoints-> 1000` instead of 100 gives a nice, light blue wall.  Unfortunately, it only plots one wall!  (*Mathematica* 11.2.0.0) A workaround could be to plot to walls individual (`wall1` and `wall2` and then use `Show[]`:  as in `Show[wall1,wall2]`.

Comment: Comment correction:  "to walls" ---> "the two walls"

Comment: I wasn't speaking about the gap between the lines forming the walls, but the gap between the two walls. [This gap](https://imgur.com/a/kBCSsVj)

Comment: Right!  I also was speaking about the gap between the walls when I wrote there is still a bit of a gap.  I don't mind the pinstripes, and with more `PlotPoints`, I think they disappear.

Comment: I tried these options, but they do not seem to help:  `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxRecursion -> 5`.

Comment: @Jon, Does this answer the question?

Comment: Not what I expected

Comment: What did you expect?  Did you want to see the figure plotted (nearly) exactly like you have it.  The rest of it should be easy.

Comment: I was looking to plot a smooth surface, and honestly this seems to me as way too  much code for this plotting. I think ill look for other ways to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows.

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[y == RealAbs[x] && 0 <= y < z, {x, y, z}]]
```

[image]